# BASH script for sorting files recursively by base filename into folders of the same name

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, file, directory

I have the following file structure:

**\HI**

- ActionPotential_hi.mp4
- ADHD_hi.mp4
- AlzheimersDisease_hi.mp4
- alzheimers_art_hi.mp4
- artificial_eye_hi.mp4
- *more files* ...

**\LO**

- ActionPotential_lo.mp4
- ADHD_lo.mp4
- AlzheimersDisease_lo.mp4
- alzheimers_art_lo.mp4
- artificial_eye_lo.mp4
- *etc.*

**\MED**

*base_filename*_med.mp4

**\STILLS**

*base_filename*_med.jpg

**\CAPTIONS**

*base_filename*.adb.xml

**\TRANSCRIPTS**

*base_filename*.txt

In order to ingest these into a MarkLogic environment, I need these rearranged to into the following structure, where *asset* is the base filename.

\ASSET

- asset_lo.mp4
- asset_med.mp4
- asset_hi.mp4
- asset.txt
- asset.adb.xml
- asset_med.jpg

**I would like a bash script to sort these out for me. Suggestions?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```sh
find . -type f -print |
while read -r pathname; do
    filename=${pathname##*/}
    case "$filename" in
        *_hi* | *_med* | *_lo*)
            # strip off last underscore and following chars
            new_dirname=${filename%_*} 
            ;;
        *)
            # strip off first dot and following chars
            new_dirname=${filename%%.*} 
            ;;
    esac
    mkdir -p "../$new_dirname"
    echo mv "$pathname" "../$new_dirname/$filename"
done
```

Untested. Remove the `echo` when you're satisfied the `mv` commands look correct.

I moved the destination directories to the parent dir of CWD because I'm not certain whether `find` will pick up the newly created directories. Can someone address this point?

Comment: @glenn Looks promising, am testing this evening.

Comment: @glenn jackman: this works well when I just have the directories with the mp4s. I get stuff like `mv ./hi/ADHD_hi.mp4 .././hi/ADHD/ADHD_hi.mp4` But when I add the folders of xml and txt I get `mv ./captions/artificial_eye.adb.xml ..//artificial_eye.adb.xml` which isn't right. Not being moved to that basename folder. I think your script isn't written to deal with the "adb.xml" files. I will play around and see if I can figure this out, but any further pointers are appreciated!

Comment: @two7s_clash, right. In the `*)` branch of the case statement, it's finding the first dot as the first char. I'll update my answer in a few minutes

Comment: nope, doesn't work for files like `CAPTIONS/artificial_eye.adb.xml` (or even `artificial_eye.xml`) or `TRANSCRIPTS/artificial_eye.txt`

Comment: @glenn: I ran this for real this AM, and found I didn't notice something. This doesn't put everything in the same basename directory per group of files. E.g. I end up with `/captions/ADHD/ADHD.xml` and `/txt/ADHD/ADHD.txt`. Each is still under a "captions" or "txt" parent. I want the txt file and the xml file (and the other files) to all be in the same ADHD directory, like so: `/ADHD/ADHD.xml` and `/ADHD/ADHD.txt`

Comment: @two7s, updated. this line `base_dirname="$dirname/$base_filename"` was the problem